# class extends MovieClip, set alpha according to buttonstate

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, extends

I use AS3 for only 4 months for my new job...I need to make a lot of emulations/simulations for several pieces of equipment. A visual ( kind of ) working example of the actual equipment for teaching purposes.

Now, i kinda understand classes regarding subclasses inheritance etc. I like to think i'm doing allright...

The Question :

I have a subclass extending `MovieClip`.
Each `Movieclip` represents the active state of the button
I have managed to set the `buttonMode` to `true` and the `alpha` to `0` by default (I know, it's amazing), what i just don't get is how i can make a custom property like `buttonState`.

I need to have the possibility to set the `buttonState` to `1`, so that the alpha becomes `1`.

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class TwoStateButton extends MovieClip 
{
    public var buttonState:int;
    public function TwoStateButton(buttonstate) 
    {
        super();

        this.buttonMode = true;
        this.alpha = 0;
        this.buttonState = buttonState;
    }
}
}
```

What i need is that when i set the `buttonState` to `1`, the `alpha` is also set to `1` and visa-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Use a setter function:

```
private var _buttonState : int = 0;

public function set buttonState ( n : int ) : void {
    _buttonState = n;
    doStuffWith ( _buttonState ); // <= use another function, or simply set alpha here
}
```

Of course, you can do whatever you want with your buttonState, but if you use a switch statement like this, you don't have to bind your button's alpha value directly to the buttonState variable:

```
    switch ( _buttonState ) {
        case 0:
            alpha = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            alpha = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            alpha =.5;
            break;
    }
```

Also, if you used a String constant instead of an int to specify your button state, you would get more readable code and more verbose trace output.